# animate a moving watermark over video using calayer

Tags: swift

I am on swift and trying to make a watermark move positions over a video. so far all I'm getting is a watermark that stays still over the video that is playing. how can I make it move? Basically what I'm trying to replicate is like the watermark from tiktok videos that pop in from one location to the other. I am really confused as to why this doesn't work. please help. thanks!

```
func processVideoWithElements(item: MediaItem, completion: @escaping ProcessCompletionHandler) {
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let clipVideoTrack = item.sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first
    let clipAudioTrack = item.sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first
    
    do {
        try compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: item.sourceAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack!, at: CMTime.zero)
    } catch {
        completion(MediaProcessResult(processedUrl: nil, image: nil), error)
    }
    
    if (clipAudioTrack != nil) {
        let compositionAudioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

        do {
            try compositionAudioTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: item.sourceAsset.duration), of: clipAudioTrack!, at: CMTime.zero)
        } catch {
            completion(MediaProcessResult(processedUrl: nil, image: nil), error)
        }
    }
   
    compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = (item.sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first?.preferredTransform)!
    
    let sizeOfVideo = item.size

let optionalLayer = CALayer()
    processAndAddElements(item: item, layer: optionalLayer)
    optionalLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sizeOfVideo.width, height: sizeOfVideo.height)
    optionalLayer.masksToBounds = true
    
    
    // animate layer ---------------------------------------
    let positionAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
    positionAnimation.beginTime = CMTime.zero.seconds
    positionAnimation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: -20, y: 100)
    positionAnimation.toValue = CGPoint(x: 280, y: 100)
    positionAnimation.duration = 3//item.sourceAsset.duration.seconds
    positionAnimation.repeatCount = 2
    positionAnimation.autoreverses = true
    optionalLayer.add(positionAnimation, forKey: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
    //------------------------------------
    
    
    
    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sizeOfVideo.width, height: sizeOfVideo.height)
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sizeOfVideo.width, height: sizeOfVideo.height)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(optionalLayer)
let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: kMediaContentTimeValue, timescale: kMediaContentTimeScale)
    videoComposition.renderSize = sizeOfVideo
    videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)
    
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: mixComposition.duration)
    
    let videoTrack = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first
    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack!)
    layerInstruction.setTransform(transform(avAsset: item.sourceAsset, scaleFactor: kMediaContentDefaultScale), at: CMTime.zero)
    
    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
    
    let processedUrl = processedMoviePath()
    clearTemporaryData(url: processedUrl, completion: completion)
    
    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exportSession?.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exportSession?.outputURL = processedUrl
    exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    
    exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        if exportSession?.status == AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed {
            completion(MediaProcessResult(processedUrl: processedUrl, image: nil), nil)
        } else {
            completion(MediaProcessResult(processedUrl: nil, image: nil), exportSession?.error)
        }
    })
```

Comment: You are making several mistakes. I would suggest following a working model like https://www.raywenderlich.com/6236502-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: what are the mistakes? the watermark shows just fine I'm just trying to make it move. I also followed raywenderlich model and got the same result

Comment: I don't think you can use Swift keypaths for CAAnimations. You have to provide a string with the path to the property you are trying to animate.

Comment: "I also followed raywenderlich model and got the same result" Well you are _not_ following that model so I have no reason to believe that. For example your begin time is wrong. But that's crucial. — Suggestion: Copy the whole tutorial, see that it works, and then slooowly turn it into code that does what you want. Commit and test frequently so you can backtrack when you make a mistake.